# acpi ppc probe failed - how to hide this message?

Tags: xubuntu, 15.04, xfce, acpi, powerpc

I read other topics about this error:

```
acpi ppc probe failed
```

But I haven't found a solution how to *turn it off*. Can ignore it - I know, but I don't want it to display at startup. Console distorts my Plymouth themes.

I don't want to fix the problem if it isn't necessary, only to hide it.

Xubuntu 15.04 xfce 64 bit